# Django serializer return OrderdDict instead of JSON

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating a Django Rest API using django-rest-framework.
I am using a JSONField to store JSON data in mongo collection. Everything is working fine but when I am fetching the record, I am getting an OrderdDict instead of json.
Here is my Model -

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models
from djongo import models

class Content(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True,auto_created = True, serialize = False)
    slides = models.JSONField(blank = True, default=[])
```

and the response I am getting  -

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "slides": "OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('name', 'Creator 1')])"
    }
]
```

but I expect a response like

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "slides": [
           {
              "id":1,
              "name":"Creator 1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

View file -

```
class ContentList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ContentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        limit = self.request.query_params.get('limit')
        if limit:
            pagination.PageNumberPagination.page_size = limit
        queryset = Content.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        return queryset
```

I tried using encoder and decoder but getting error -

```
    slides = models.JSONField(blank = True, encoder= None, decoder=None, default=[])
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoder'
```

Contentserializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from testApp.models import Content
 
 
class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = '__all__'
```

The Django version is 3.0.

How can I do this? I am new to python and started learning recently and stuck here for last 2 days. Tried a lot of solution but not working.

Comment: How can I return dict instead of OrderedDict? As per App developer, he is not able to parse this in kotlin.

Comment: can you share the ContentSerializer code ? and also  I don't see ContentSerializer being called.

Comment: Ho @vbid ContentSerializer code added in question

Comment: check if my answer works :)

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the data to the  ContentSerializer class to get the output in JSON format.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    limit = self.request.query_params.get('limit')
    if limit:
        pagination.PageNumberPagination.page_size = limit
    queryset = Content.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    data = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
    return Response({"data":data})
```